# Diagonal entries in Smith normal form

Tags: linear-algebra

given a Matrix A,

On what property does it depend how many non zero diagonal entries A has in the Smith normal form?

I'm interested in the case when A has less rows than columns

Comment: the rank of $A$

Comment: and after the computation can you say which row / columns are linear dependent of A?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: A = D*S*T is Smith decomposition. (D, T unimodular matrices) If you got the three matrices D,S,T can you then say which rows/columns of A are linear dependent. And the other question is if A is a sparse Matrix is then D and T also a sparse Matrix?